# How to add bootstrap for below laravel 5 form

Tags: laravel-5

Below is the output of form.

[image]

I want to keep this both 2 fields in a one row. How can I do that using bootstrap? This is my view code.

```
{!! Form::label('titles', 'Title') !!}

{!! Form::text('title',null,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-1">
       {!! Form::label('titles', 'Title') !!}
 </div>
 <div class="form-group col-md-11">
       {!! Form::text('title',null,['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
 </div>
```

Comment: That's work fine. Thank you. Can you explain me what is meant by col-md-1 and col-md-11?

Comment: its bootstrap columns. You can read more about it from https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: How to increase the width of label above?

Comment: Ok Igot that. Thank you